# My raspberry pi 4 won't boot

Tags: boot-issues, reboot

I have OMV installed on my Rasberry pi 4. I also have Portainer installed, I wanted to install Nginx Proxy Manager on a docker container so I though I should uninstall nginx that I had on my rpi4. I ran the following two commands :

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I then rebooted it, but I wasn't able to connect to it via SSH.
I connected to a monitor to see what's happening :

[image]

[image]

Not sure what's wrong other tan the rrdcached that keeps failing.
Is there any way to fix this? Or at least to get the data I had on an sql lite database?
My database is on a docker container and if there's a way to just backup those files directly from my RPI4 SD Card that would be awesome too.
Thanks.

Comment: connect to keyboard and monitor - see what's happening

Comment: @JaromandaX I just added a screenshot of what's going on

Comment: Just put your sd card to a linux machine.  You should be able to retrieve any files... Or even image the sd and access it via an application if you must use windows.

Comment: @Abel is there no way to fix this issues?

Comment: Probably is, but if you care about your database, retrieve it before you try things.  Once it's retrieved, try things; you should know at least one thing that will definitely work.

Comment: @Veoxer you are asking two unrelated questions ... boot issue and data recovery ... please ask them separately, so that they can be answered

Comment: Restore from your backup.